# trigger click event when has class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a function when has an specific class, in this case  `Clicked` so I want to return the alert `(unliked)`

**HTML**

```
<div class="social">
<div class="LikePost default"></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".social").find(".LikePost").trigger("click"); /*when has class "clicked"*/
alert("unliked")
```

**TRIGGERED FUNCTION**

```
$('.LikePost').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("default")) {
    $(this).addClass("Clicked");
    $(this).removeClass("default");
    alert("post liked");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("default");
    $(this).removeClass("Clicked");
    alert("post unliked");
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(".clicked").trigger("click")` ?

Comment: small, quick and awesome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright x-D

```
$(".Clicked").trigger("click")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your trigger like this:

```
$('.LikePost').on('click', function(){

// just invert classes state
$(this).toggleClass("default");
$(this).toggleClass("Clicked");

// if is default, its liked, if not, its not liked
if($(this).hasClass("default")) {
    alert("post liked");
} else {
    alert("post unliked");
}
});
```

And if you want to manually trigger all liked posts, just do it:

```
$('.Clicked').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Awesome arrangement. but does `toggleClass` deletes the prior class and adds the new one? or just add both classes to the element and uses the selected between parenthesis?

Comment: toggle will add if it's not there, and remove if it's there
so the first time you click it, it will remove default and add Clicked, next time will add default and remove Clicked and so on

Comment: that would be the same? `$(this).toggleClass("default, Clicked");`

Comment: almost, you can do it this way: $(this).toggleClass("default Clicked");